# How to CSS Child element height according to parent height?

Tags: html, css

I already know solution by using flex method but that not helpful for me. So give me an alternate solution.

I want the height of child div is the same as parent div how can I achieve this?

HTML Code:

```html
<div style="float: left;width: 100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;position:  relative;">
    <div style="float: left;width: 10%;border-right: 1px solid #000;height: 100%;">
        <p style="font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;margin: 0">Customer</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 89.7%;height: 100%;">
        <p style="font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;padding-left: 5px;margin: 0">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is explained further on ['The great collapse' section of this css tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) when an element has any float styles, the parent will be 0 height iff it's the only child, the height:100% should work once the float is removed from the child div.

The float style has a few other side effects which generally leads me to avoid using them, flex styles and absolute /relative positioned elements can usually achieve the required UI effects with the exception of positioning images in an article with a WYSWIG.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the left div absolute (floating the right div right and adding a margin-left of the same with (10% in your example):

```
<div style="float: left;width: 100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;position:  relative;">
  <div style="width: 10%;border-right: 1px solid #000;height: 100%;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;margin: 0">Customer</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;width: 89.7%;height: 100%;margin-left: 10%;">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;padding-left: 5px;margin: 0">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only drawback, if the text in the left dif makes it higher then the left div, it will overflow its parent...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this issue.

Your way with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var parent_height = $('#parent-div').height();
  
  $('#child-div-01').height(parent_height);
  
});
```

```css
#parent-div{float: left;width: 100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;position:  relative;}

#child-div-01{float: left;width: 10%;border-right: 1px solid #000;height: 100%;}

#child-div-01 p.para-1{font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;margin: 0}

#child-div-02{float: left;width: 89.7%;height: 100%;}

#child-div-02 p.para-2{font-size: 18px;padding: 2px;padding-left: 5px;margin: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="child-div-01">
        <p class="para-1">Customer</p>
    </div>
    <div id="child-div-02">
        <p class="para-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/BOPXBW)

Second totally CSS way(without using FlexBox):

```css
#parent-div{position: relative; overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.child{display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
.child-left{width: 15%; height: 100%; border-right: 1px solid #000;}
.child-right{width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
  <div class="child child-left">
    <p>Customer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child child-right">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/xaJvGN)